# {{store url=''}} is strangely not working

Tags: magento-1.9, template

in one of my static blocks I have this HTML markup:

```
<ul>
<li><a href="{{store url='agb'}}">AGB</a></li>
<li><a href="{{store url='impressum'}}">Impressum</a></li>
</ul>
```

It should produce a link to the page with the url identifier 'agb', so mystore.de/agb. But the actual output looks like that:

```
<a href="{{store url='agb'}}">AGB</a>
```

So nothing changes. I am going insane and google doesn't deliver. Please help!!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

your code is write.just cross check the following answer.

In your static block click on `show / hide editor` button now you will see the text area place your code here

ie `<a href="{{store url='about-us'}}">About Us</a>`

and click on the save button.

Comment: I did that. Of course... I think it has more to do with how I display the code in my theme. I do echo $this->getChildHtml('footer_links');

Comment: check Rahul answer wther you have followed same step or not

Comment: I know the basics and did that.

Answer (score 0):

Please Check whether WYSIWYG editor is enabled or not! Hide Editor and paste your code!

---

[image]

---

[image]